# Why can a std::vector be constructed using two ints?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, type-conversion, explicit-constructor

`vector<T>` has a constructor that takes the size of the vector, and as far as I know it is *explicit*, which can be proved by the fact that the following code fails to compile

```
void f(std::vector<int> v);
int main()
{
    f(5);
}
```

What I cannot understand and am asking you to explain is why the following code compiles

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph(5, 5);
```

Not only does it compile, it actually resizes graph to 5 and sets each element to a vector of five zeros, i.e. does the same as would the code I would normally write:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph(5, std::vector<int>(5));
```

How? Why?

Compiler: MSVC10.0

---

OK, seems it's an MSVC bug (yet another one). If someone can elaborate on the bug in an answer (i.e. summarize the cases where it is reproduced) I would gladly accept it

Comment: This (rightly) doesn't compile on GCC 4.7. Yet another MSVC++ non-standard weirdness. They probably just forgot to mark the constructor `explicit`, you could dig in `<vector>` to check that.

Comment: @syam: I'm glad to heat it fails to compile on GCC, but what's really weird is that the first example compiles on MSCV, while the other does not. That's what really strange

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Neither compiles on VS2012; the error message states the constructor is `explicit`

Comment: Why don't you take a look in library sources?

Comment: @jrok: I did - the constructor is explicit, yet the code is not rejected

Comment: I meant the implementation of `vector(size_type, const T&, const T& Allocator)` constructor.

Comment: @jrok: See my answer, this is actually tricky; it's not invoking the constructor you think it is.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I can't get the `f(5)` code to compile on VS2010; rejected because constructor is `explicit`. The `graph` initialization is invoking the constructor that takes 2 iterators.

Comment: @Praetorian: I really fail to understand how is int an iterator?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan It's a template type that happens to have iterator in its name. *Any* two equal types could be considered for that constructor (except ones that would also be allowed for the `(size, value)` constructor which the standard mandates would be preferred).

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan The iterator type is a template parameter, so it can match anything. In VS2012 SFINAE is being used to reject that constructor. `template<class _Iter> vector(_Iter _First, _Iter Last, typename enable_if<_Is_iterator<_Iter>::value, void>:: type ** = 0) { ... }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not really a bug. The question is what could go wrong to allow the second piece of code while the first does not compile?

The issue is that while it seems obvious to you what constructor you want to call when you do:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph(5, 5);
```

it is not so clear for the compiler. In particular there are two constructor overloads that can potentially accept the arguments:

```
vector(size_type,const T& value = T());

template <typename InputIterator>
vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

The first one requires the conversion of `5` to `size_type` (which is unsigned), while the second is a perfect match, so that will be the one picked up by the compiler...

... but the compiler requires that the second overload, if the deduced type `InputIterator` is integral behaves as if it was a call to:

```
vector(static_cast<size_type>(first),static_cast<T>(last))
```

What the C++03 standard effectively mandates is that the second argument is *explicitly* converted from the original type `int` to the destination type `std::vector<int>`. Because the conversion is explicit you get the error.

The C++11 standard changes the wording to use SFINAE to disable the iterator constructor if the argument is not really an input iterator, so in a C++11 compiler the code should be rejected (which is probably the reason some have claimed this to be a bug).

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like it's calling this constructor:

```
template <class InputIterator>
vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
  const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

I'm not sure where `explicit` comes into it, because the constructor takes multiple parameters. It's not auto casting from an int to a vector.

Comment: The standard explicitly prohibits using the two-iterator constructor when the other constructor would also be a possible match.

Comment: I don't think I understand... How is int an input iterator?

Comment: `InputIterator` is just the template parameter - it can be any type.

Comment: @MarkB That may well be true - my knowledge of the std libraries is not very extensive. I'm just saying what the compiler appears to be doing - not what it should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an extension, not a bug.

The constructor being invoked is the one that takes two iterators (but really, the signature will match any two parameters of the same type); it then invokes a specialization for when the two iterators are actually `int`, which explicitly constructs a `value_type` using the value of `end` and populates the vector with `begin` copies of it.

Comment: I don't think I understand... What does int mean as an iterator?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: `std::vector` has a constructor that takes a begin and end iterator. It's defined as something like `template<typename _It> vector(_It first, _It last)`, which matches your invocation. It then calls into a function with various overloads based on the type of `_It`, one of the overloads handling the case where `_It` is an `int`.

Comment: To answer your question, it's __not__ an iterator, but the code handles the case where you give it an int.

Comment: If it's true what you're saying, it's the worst extension I ever saw. (I'm afraid it makes some twisted sense, though)

Comment: It is not really an *extension* the C++03 standard requires this behavior.