# How can I implement a class which can be constructed with an input iterator?

Tags: c++

The `std::vector` class has a convenient constructor which allows any input iterator for its parameter. I would like to implement a similar pattern in my own class, because the class needs to take in some collection when instantiated, but I would like to have the iterator over that collection for encapsulation purposes. One way that I thought of to do this is template-ing the whole class with the input iterator type, but that can't be what STL does, because `vector` is clearly only templated with the type being iterated over. Of course, one option is a templated generator function, but I'd really like to know how it's done by compilers that implement STL - somehow, the `InputIterator` type is a typename specific only to the constructor, even if constructors can't be templated.

(Yes, I have tried to look at `vector.tpp` but I could not understand it).

Comment: "even if constructors can't be templated." That's the thing - they *can* be, and it's exactly what `vector` does.

Comment: @jrok Well, that seems easy then. What is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960849/c-template-constructor) all about then?

Comment: Template parameters of a constructor need to be deduced because there is no way to specify them explicitly.

Comment: @jrok In that case my question seems pretty trivial - is there any reason to keep it up?

Comment: @VF1: Still a perfectly reasonable question, unambiguous and easy to find, and with a clear answer. If you delete it, someone else will ask it in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class should have a templated constructor (templated on the iterator type):

```
class my_class {

    template <typename InputIterator>
    my_class(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: I really wanted to try this but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960849/c-template-constructor) deterred me from doing so.

Comment: @VF1 The important requirement the OP wants in that question is *I wish to have a non-template class with a template constructor **with no arguments***. This cannot be done because, as James' answer states, for a templated constructor, the template arguments must be deduced.

Comment: @VF1: The question in the reference you provided is about a templated constructor that **does not take any argument**. In your case it does take at least one (or more likely two). In any case, what I'm explaining in my post is exactly what the STL containers do.

Comment: @CassioNeri Yes - I get it now. I'd accept, but I have to wait 5 minutes.

Comment: @VF1 When you implement this, also be aware of pitfalls like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427951/implicit-conversion-from-int-to-vector) where the templated constructor may turn out to be a better match than another constructor (that you'd intuitively except to be a better match)

Comment: @Praetorian thanks for the advice. What I'm currently working on only has one constructor, but I'll keep what you said in mind for the future.